# Multiple hostnames for a Synology NAS in local network

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, synology

Is it possible to set up a Synology DS918+ NAS (which is just a Linux system) to be accessible via

- `http://diskstation.local` and
- `http://laura.local`

at the same time? I have set up a reverse proxy on my NAS that routes to a different server in a docker container when you access it via `laura.local` than when you access it via `diskstation.local`

Answer (score 2):

Synology offer DNS Server package:

https://www.synology.com/en-global/dsm/packages/DNSServer

You can configure it for local resolution and  let it forward everything else to an external DNS (e.g.: your provider DNS)

https://robpickering.com/configuring-synology-for-forward-and-reverse-internal-dns-resolution/

In the master zone you can add many entries you need that resolve your hosts and point to NAS IP:

```
diskstation.local -> your NAS IP
laura.local -> your NAS IP
```

Remember also to configure the router or the server that offering DHCP in your local network in order to provide your Synology NAS as DNS server.

In this way you don't need to create a host entry in each device in your local network

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you can add entries in your DNS server for the `.local` zone.

Another alternative is to add entries to `/etc/hosts` (Mac / Unix) or to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.txt` where you map the host names to IP addresses. This operation has to be done on every client computer where you want to use the hostname.

Comment: I want that host to be accessible from all computers and phones in my network, not just the ones i set up /etc/hosts for and I don't own a DNS server

Comment: You need a DNS server to set up mapping between names and IP addresses. Your NAS unit might have one, your router might have one. You need to research it yourself.